# binary compatibility vs backward compatibilty

Tags: terminology, shared-libraries, backwards-compatibility, binary-compatibility

I've been reading some details about Qt d-pointer and came across the binary compatibility term. Is this the same as backward compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backward compatibility of shared libraries includes:

1. **Binary** compatibility
2. **Source** compatibility
3. **Behavioral** compatibility

So, the answer is NO. Binary compatibility is only the part of backward compatibility.

See the ["Kinds of Compatibility: Source, Binary, and Behavioral"](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/kinds_of_compatibility) for more info.